Finding majority land use class within polygon in QGIS
I have a polygon layer containing the wards (neighborhoods) of an area. It has only one column in the attribute table, called "WD21CD" which is a string with the unique code for every ward (total of 69 rows). I also have another point layer containing land use (LU) classes. It has only one column in the attribute table, called "categoryname" (total of 42350 rows).
My goal is to find the majority LU class per ward and create another column in the polygon layer which will contain that majority class.
I have tried the tool Join Attributes by Location (Summary) but the resulting joined layer is the same as my original polygon layer with the same attribute table. Below is the screenshot of the parameters I selected.

A hypothetical result is shown below: instead of NULL values in the "categoryname" column I will have the majority LU class:

QGIS 3.34.10-Prizren

You can use the expression:
array_majority(
    array:=overlay_intersects(
        layer:='points',
        expression:="rasterval"
        )
    )[0]

It will create an array of all values in the column rasterval of the intersecting points in the layer points, then calculate the majority value. Change rasterval and points to match your data.


This answer isn't based on QGIS, but I solved my issue in R:
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

wd <- "path/"

area_data <- st_read(paste0(wd, "wards_2021.geojson"))
point_data <- st_read(paste0(wd, "poi.geojson"))

# spatial join of LU points to wards
lu_within_wards <- st_join(point_data, area_data, join = st_within)

# drop geometry (remove spatial, I added later again)
lu_within_wards_no_geom <- st_drop_geometry(lu_within_wards)

# Group by ward and count LU types, then find the most common
most_frequent_lu <- lu_within_wards_no_geom %>%
  group_by(WD21CD) %>%  # ward ID column
  count(categoryname, sort = TRUE) %>%  # here I count LU occurrences
  slice(1)  # here I keep the most frequent LU for each ward

# left join to add the most frequent LU back to the ward polygons
wards_with_lu <- area_data %>%
  left_join(most_frequent_lu, by = "WD21CD")

head(wards_with_lu)

# export
st_write(wards_with_lu, "path/wards_LU.geojson")

